# Is there a sheaf model where the Weak Markov's principle fails?

Tags: general-topology, logic, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

We define a real number $x$ to be pseudopositive if $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $ \neg \neg (x > y)  \vee \neg \neg (y > 0) $.

The Weak Markov's Principle (WMP) is the axiom that every pseudopositive real number is a positive real number. This clearly follows from the analytic Markovs Principle which states that the double negations above simplify, so it is clearly true in the effective topos and in any CC + MP setting. The idea behind the generalization is that the WMP apparently holds in intuitionistic models with a continuity principle.

This then makes me wonder for which sheaf models it holds. Is there a sheaf model where it fails? Does it hold for say, sheaves over manifolds?

EDIT: Translating this question to a standard one for real functions on a topological space which is a standard question about topology, the question is for what topological spaces $X$ we have the following property:

We can define a continuous real *function* $f(x)$ to be pseudopositive if for any continuous real function $g(x)$ on $X$ we have

$\textrm{int} (\textrm{cl}(\{ x: f(x) > g(x) \})) \bigcup \textrm{int} (\textrm{cl}(\{ x: g(x) > 0 \})) = X $

and we may say that the space $X$ satisfies the weak markov property if the pseudopositive real functions on $X$ are just the positive functions on $X$.

A quick sanity check tells is that this is automatically true if every open subset is clopen, which includes discrete spaces and stone spaces like the Cantor space/p-adic numbers or the Irrational numbers, or more generally if they satisfy that the interior of the closure of the open support of a continuous function simplifies (analytic MP), but we are interested in whether spaces that look more like $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy this weaker property.

Comment: Which real numbers are you referring to? I assume Dedekind cuts.

Comment: @MarkSaving Yes, Dedekind cuts. Though the modulated Cauchy reals are also interesting, since locally connected grothendieck topoi satisfy LPO so that the modulated Cauchy reals will automatically satisfy analytic LPO and therefore also analytic Markov, and it would also be interesting to see how much the locally connected condition for that can be weakened.

Comment: But of course, WMP for Dedekind reals is the case that is of most interest to me personally since for sheaves over manifolds the Cauchy reals trivially satisfy analytic MP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is fairly complicated, but here's a tl;dr:

- There are spaces $X$ where $\mathsf{Sh}(X)$ invalidates WMP.
- However no "spaces that look more like $\mathbb{R}^n$" will work.

> Thm $1$: $\mathsf{Sh}(\mathbb{R}^n) \vDash \ulcorner f \text{ is pseudopositive} \urcorner \to f > 0$

By the usual semantics for $\mathsf{Sh}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, thm 1 holds if and only if, for each open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, whenever $U \Vdash \ulcorner f \text{ is pseudopositive} \urcorner$ then $U \Vdash f > 0$ (See Mac Lane & Moerdijk, *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* pg 316 for this theorem).
Notice this implication is at the level of the metatheory, so we're allowed to use proof by contradiction, etc. without worry.

With this in mind, fix an open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and assume that $U \not \Vdash f > 0$. We'll show that $U \not \Vdash \ulcorner f \text{ is pseudopositive} \urcorner$.

Now $U \not \Vdash f > 0$ means that $f$ is not strictly positive on $U$. If there's a point with $f(p) < 0$ then $f$ has a neighborhood on which $f < 0$, so clearly is not pseudopositive. So we may assume $f \geq 0$ on $U$, but is not strictly positive. Fix a $p \in U$ with $f(p) = 0$. We'll build a function $g$ so that $U \not \Vdash \lnot \lnot (g > 0) \lor \lnot \lnot (f > g)$.
To do this, we need to know $g \leq 0$ on an open set and $f \leq g$ on an open set. Moreover, since truth in a sheaf topos is local, we'll need to know that we can't get our way out of this problem by moving closer to $p$. So we'll need these properties to hold on *every* neighborhood of $p$.

Some thought shows that $g(x) = 2f(x) \sin \left ( \frac{1}{\lVert x-p \rVert} \right )$ does the trick. Since $f \geq 0$, we see $g \leq 0$ whenever $\sin \left ( \frac{1}{\lVert x-p \rVert} \right ) \leq 0$, which happens on an open set in every neighborhood of $p$. Moreover, whenever $\sin \left ( \frac{1}{\lVert x-p \rVert} \right ) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ (which also happens on an open set in every neighborhood of $p$) we'll have $g \geq f$! The only question is whether $g$ is continuous, but since $f(p) = 0$ the squeeze theorem tells us that taking $g(p) = 0$ gives a continuous function on $U$.

So then if $f$ is any function where $U \not \Vdash f > 0$, we also have $U \not \Vdash \ulcorner f \text{ is pseudopositive} \urcorner$, so (using LEM in the metatheory) $U \Vdash \ulcorner f \text{ is pseudopositive} \urcorner$ implies $U \Vdash f > 0$ for every $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, as desired.

In pictures, given some blue function $f$ which is $0$ at the $p$, we build an orange function $g$ which, in any neighborhood of $p$, has both $g \geq f$ and $g \leq 0$ on an open set. This witnesses the non-pseudopositivity of $f$ under the assumption that $f(p) = 0$ somewhere.

[image: a plot of the f and g we built in the proof]

Now, since truth is local in a sheaf topos, we immediately get a corollary:

> Thm $2$: If $X$ is locally euclidean (for instance, if $X$ is a manifold) then $\mathsf{Sh}(X) \vDash \text{WMP}$

For the proof, notice that we can open cover $X$ by spaces homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since each element of the cover validates WMP by Thm $1$, we see that $X$ does as well.

---

I've actually had this answer drafted for over a week now, but I really wanted to find a space invalidating WMP. After some googling, I found Diener's [*Constructive Reverse Mathematics*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.05495.pdf), which in section 7.2.5 gives the result I promised at the top of this answer.

Fix a nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$. Let $X = \mathbb{N} \cup \{ \omega \}$ where a base of the topology is given by

- $\{ n \}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$
- $A \cup \{ \omega \}$ for each $A \in \mathcal{U}$

Then consider the real $f(n) = 2^{-n}$, $f(\omega) = 0$. You can check this is pseudopositive, but it is not positive since $f(\omega) = 0$.

**Edit:** Here's a proof that $f$ is pseudopositive. Let $g$ be some other function. Then exactly one of $\{ n \mid g(n) > 0 \}$ or $\{ n \mid g(n) \leq 0 \}$ is $\mathcal{U}$-big. Note that if $A$ is $\mathcal{U}$-big, then $A \cup \{ \omega \} \Vdash \lnot \lnot \varphi$ exactly when $\varphi$ holds on each $n \in A$, but possibly not on $\omega$.

If $A = \{ n \mid g(n) > 0 \}$ is $\mathcal{U}$-big, then look at the open cover $\Big \{ A \cup \{ \omega \}, \{ n \} \text{ for each $g(n) \leq 0$} \Big \}$. On each $\{ n \}$ we have $f > g$, and on $A \cup \{ \omega \}$ we have $\lnot \lnot (g > 0)$ (since $g > 0$ is true on $A$). So $\mathsf{Sh}(X) \vDash \lnot \lnot (g > 0) \lor \lnot \lnot (f > g)$.
If instead $B = \{ n \mid g(n) \leq 0 \}$ is $\mathcal{U}$-big, then we get an open cover
$\Big \{ B \cup \{ \omega \}, \{ n \} \text{ for each $g(n) > 0$} \Big \}$. Now on each $\{ n \}$ we have $g > 0$, and on $B \cup \{ \omega \}$ we have $\lnot \lnot (f > g)$ (since $f > 0 \geq g$ is true on $B$). So again we have $\mathsf{Sh}(X) \vDash \lnot \lnot (g > 0) \lor \lnot \lnot (f > g)$, as desired.

In fact, this paper has a *ton* of interesting results about the internal logic of sheaf topoi, so you'll almost certainly enjoy giving it a read! I know I did.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you! This answer had everything I wished for in an answer to my question and more. WMP viewed as a topological property is pretty nontrivial so it's definitely interesting and useful that it is satisfied both by locally euclidean spaces and by stone spaces. I assume that means it also holds for sheaves over Adeles?

Comment: Also very interesting that the counterexample requires a free ultrafilter on the integers

Comment: The paper you linked was a great primer on WMP. In particular it shows it for first countable spaces

Comment: I took a close look at the proof and found that it is possible to weaken the assumption that the space is first countable quite a bit, and that it can be modified a bit to work for all sequential spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strengthening of @HallaSurvivor 's answer above and to the proof in [Constructive Reverse Mathematics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.05495). The assumption used there was that the space be first countable, but the only part of first countability used there is that the space satisfies the property that all dense subsets are sequentially dense (dense subsets have a net that converges to any point, sequentially dense nets contain a sequence that converges to any point).

This is trivially true by definition in Fréchet–Urysohn spaces, where the sequential closure equals the topological closure. Therefore, the sheaf topos over any Fréchet–Urysohn space satisfies the weak markov principle.

More generally, it looks like we can further weaken the assumption in the proof, and treating the case of the dense set being the whole set as trivial, we only *really* need that every dense open proper subset contains a sequence that converges to at least one point in its complement, to get the necessary contradiction in the proof. Since a commonly given criteria for sequential spaces is that any subset that is not closed has a sequence that converges to a point in its closure, this is satisfied.

This would imply that sheaf topoi over any sequential space satisfy WMP.

Comment: Alternatively, we can reword the proof by contradiction part that holds in any space, as a proof that the dense open subset $[x > 0]$ is also sequentially closed. For sequential spaces, sequentially closed spaces are closed, and closed dense subsets must be the whole space.

Comment: Another comment: WMP is also unfortunately a bit less useful without weak countable choice, since sheaves over R satisfy WMP, but not that every function from a complete metric space to a metric space is strongly extensional: http://math.fau.edu/richman/docs/wmp.pdf